# Calling Kendo UI DatePicker using prototype

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, prototypejs

We use prototype.js for javascript but we are now implementing the Kendo UI DatePicker and I am confused on how to approach an issue. Given the following:

```
function MyClass()
{
 this.Name = $('inputName');
 this.LastName $('inputLastName');
 this.GridViewInputs;
}

MyClass.prototype.init = function()
{
  //some event observe methods here
}

MyClass.protype.setUpDatePickers = function()
{
   //grab all input values from a gridview and attach a date picker to each
   this.GridViewInputs = $$('.Dates');

   //HERE IS MY PROBLEM, I AM NOT SURE HOW TO CALL THE FUNCTION BELOW FROM HERE
   //AND PASSING IT EACH INPUT
}


 $j(document).ready(function() {
                // create DatePicker from input HTML element
                $(myInput passed here).kendoDatePicker();
      });
```

The problem i have is that I cant really use this.GridViewInputs inside the $j function because it would say its not recognized, I believe because it's outside the object.

- Can I include this call inside my MyClass object so that I can pass my values and how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call the `setUpDatePickers` method inside the document ready function?

2 ways to call it - either after you have created an instance of `MyClass`

```
var t = new MyClass();
t.setupDatePickers();
```

or directly from the prototype

```
MyClass.protype.setUpDatePickers()
```

If you call it directly from the prototype you do not have `this` available - so it might not be the best way

Also inside of `MyClass.protype.setUpDatePickers` to put the date pickers on the inputs you'll need to do one of the following - I'm not exactly sure if the first one will work as I haven't used kendo before - but the 2nd one will work.

```
$$('.Dates').invoke('kendoDatePicker');
//
//OR
//
$$('.Dates').each(function(input){
    input.kendoDatePicker();
});
```